# Converting landscape table to portrait in thesis book format a4 size

Tags: tables, landscape

I have a code like this where I made landspace document but I wanted to add this document to my thesis book which doesn't allow me to have landscape page so I request someone to help me change this format to portrait.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.2\textwidth}
                              p{.35\textwidth}
                              X
                              >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.15\textwidth}
                              >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.175\textwidth}}
\caption{Related works on computer vision (Comparison table)}
\label{my-label}\\
\toprule 
Topic & Goal & Idea & Technique  & Use case\\
\midrule 
\endfirsthead
\toprule 
Topic & Goal & Technique & Idea  & Use case\\
\midrule 
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Computer vision tasks & Image classification (CNN, AlexNet)  & Given an input that contains K images, each labelled with M distinct classes. We use the training set to train a classifier to learn what every one of the classes are like. Finally evaluate the quality of classifier by predicting labels for new set of images &  Classifying images into distinct category & With better classifier it could predict more images\\
\midrule


% Next comes YOLO versions and definitions and different classification techniques within the cv such as CNN, fast etc. 
\end{xltabular}%



\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of table with fairly wide columns]

Comment: Start by removing the landscape environment and your table should be in portrait orientation.

Comment: If i remove landscape, it just overlaps the last two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? In addition to removing the `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}` directives, I've also changed the relative column widths quite a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,xltabular,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ @{}
  P{.15\textwidth}
  P{.15\textwidth}
  L
  P{.15\textwidth}
  P{.15\textwidth}
  @{} }
  
\caption{Related works on computer vision (Comparison table)}
\label{my-label}\\
\toprule 
Topic & Goal & Idea & Technique  & Use case\\
\midrule 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, cont'd}\\[1ex]
\toprule 
Topic & Goal & Technique & Idea  & Use case\\
\midrule 
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Computer vision tasks & 
Image classification (CNN, AlexNet)  & 
Given an input that contains $K$ images, each labelled with $M$ distinct classes. We use the training set to train a classifier to learn what every one of the classes are like. Finally evaluate the quality of classifier by predicting labels for new set of images &  
Classifying images into distinct category & 
With better classifier it could predict more images \\

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: i use documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book} for my thesis book. Could you please use this same class and give example?

Comment: this works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KSp - You're most welcome! Changing `\documentclass{article}` to `\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}` and recompiling wasn't too tedious, I gather. :-)

Comment: I just added the packages to my main book and it fixed it.

Comment: one small issue. CHAPTER 3. RELATED WORKS ON COMPUTER VISION COMPARISON TABLE 20 i get this on top of header. how to remove the page number from the side and keep it at the bottom.

Comment: @KSp - Please post a new query.